# My SQLite in android studio with DISTINCT order question

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

[image: This is my database]

This is my database table call "BREAKFAST_TABLE" I want to keep date that not duplicate to list

This is my code

```
public List<String> get_notSameDate(String status)
    {
        List<String> return_Food=new ArrayList<>();

        //COLUMN_DATE is "DATE"
        //status is "BREAKFAST_TABLE"
        String queryString="SELECT DISTINCT"+COLUMN_DATE+" FROM "+status;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String date=cursor.getString(0);
                return_Food.add(date);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return return_Food;
    }
```

I using this code it always crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though we don't know what error it crashes with, I believe it fails because of missing space symbol between "DISTINCT" and the column name:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT"+COLUMN_DATE+" FROM "+status;
```

fixed:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT "+COLUMN_DATE+" FROM "+status;
```